# The url after the MVC app runs is Home/Index. How to change it?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

After I run my program which is in MVC, the url it goes is Home/Index. Where to change this?
I want to check if the user is logged in, to redirect so some other page. If he isn't logged in, then the url can be Home/Index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You sort of asking two things.

You application automatically goes to `Home/Index` because of this, you'll find the below code  if you double click your `Global.asax` file.

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
     new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } 
     );
}
```

Change the *"Home"* and *"Index"* strings for your custom default.

Now, for your login requirement, you could leave the default route and do this:

```
public class HomeController
{
 public ActionResult Index()
 {
   if(!Request.IsAuthenticated)//if NOT authenticated
   {//go somewhere else
    return RedirectToAction(actioName, controllertName); 
   } 
   //for logged in users
   return View();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using MVC you should look at using the [Authorize action filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute.aspx)

The url you go to on not being authenticated is set in the web.config if you are using forms authentication.

Answer (score 0):

For the first part of your question (the route), check out the default route, its usually set to

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );
```

Which is in your Global.asax file in the web application, and this is why you are seeing what you are seeing.

You really need to read up on ASP.Net Routing - http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/controllers-and-routing/asp-net-mvc-routing-overview-cs